# Boot2docker windows change timezone

Tags: timezone, boot2docker

how do you change the timezone in boot2docker for windows?

[Tiny Core Linux FAQ](http://tinycorelinux.net/faq.html#timezone) talks about setting **tz** variable. I suppose its bootloader variable, but I can't figure out correct place for it?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the local timezone information is stored in a file called `/etc/localtime` or `/etc/timezone` on a Linux system. They contain strings like `America/New_York`, or `Europe/Berlin`.

Unfortunately there are [several](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/476) [issues](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/891) reported at github about problems setting the timezone in a boot2docker VM. Maybe you find some helpful ideas, there.

Comment: Thank you, I found those too, didn't help really. I was hoping to somehow set the tz bootcode, like [here](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=9624.0). But don't know where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, this is what worked for me. I guess it only applies to Windows 7 / Docker Toolkit anymore, but here goes:

### boot2docker machine TZ settings for Windows 7 / Docker Toolkit

You need to add some permanent settings to the docker machine
as  per the [boot2docker FAQ](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/17.03.x/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)

- create `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh` in the docker machine
- give exec flag `chmod u+x bootlocal.sh`

As described in the [Tiny Core Linux forum](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=5017.msg27012#msg27012) and [Wiki](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:time_zone)

```
cd /var/lib/boot2docker
# fetch and mount timezone data
tce-fetch.sh tzdata.tcz
mkdir ext
sudo mount tzdata.tcz ext -t squashfs -o loop,ro,bs=4096
# I needed Europe/Berlin; find your timezone by scanning the ./ext directory
cp ext/usr/local/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin ./Europe-Berlin.tz
# delete files that are no longer needed
umount ext
rm -rf ext tzdata.tcz
```

Europe-Berlin.tz should survive restarts of the docker machine

Finally, copy the timezone file when starting up docker-machine by adding the following to the bootlocal script

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /var/lib/boot2docker/Europe-Berlin.tz /etc/localtime
```

You should see the correct time now when you enter `date`